# How to autorun a python script at startup in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sockets, python-sockets

I have a client script which needs to get invoked at start up. The script runs fine if I start it manually using **systemctl start dummy.service**. The server script is running on another machine.
But if I reboot my machine it does not get start and when checked the status it shows as **failed with result exit-code**. When I start my machine and when linux is loading all the services before going into log in screen, It shows that **failed to start dummy.service, Network is unreachable**. What could be the problem exactly?

Here is my dummy.service code

path /lib/systemd/system/dummy.service

```
Description=Dummy Service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/client.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And my python script in /usr/bin is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.1.105",1234))
msg=s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl enable dummy.service
```

if you are not root user:

```
chmod 744 the_pythonscript.py
chmod 644 dummy.service
```

Comment: systemct enable dummy.service ,This works fine when invoked manullay through terminal but when I restart the PC it does not get autostart. **I am the root user.** When I restart my machine at linux startup it shows me **failed to start dummy.service, Network is unreachable.**